# Rails won't load default project template, says `missing postgres.yml` file whenever I enter `rails new`

Tags: ruby, postgresql, terminal, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

Whenever I try and start a new project with `rails new -d postgresql -T`, it gives me an incomplete default project and tells me I am missing `config/databases/postgresql.yml` which, as far as I know, shouldn't even exist in the first place.

Has anyone come across this issue or know some things I can try to resolve the conflict? Below is the result of me trying to create a new project. I can navigate to the folder where the template is but I don't know if doing anything there will help.

```
Could not find "config/databases/postgresql.yml" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
/Users/jasonrodriguez/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates
jasonrodriguez:~ jasonrodriguez$ rails new micropost
Using -d postgresql -T from /Users/jasonrodriguez/.railsrc
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   identical  app/assets/images/.keep
   identical  app/mailers/.keep
   identical  app/models/.keep
   identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
   identical  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
Could not find "config/databases/postgresql.yml" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
/Users/jasonrodriguez/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates
jasonrodriguez:~ jasonrodriguez$
```

I tried deleting `.railsrc` and restarting my computer. I also made sure my gemfile has `gem pg` and my `databse.yml` does not have `username` and my adapter is set correctly to `adapter:postgresql` . Still, the project only gives me an incomplete starter template which consists of :

```
app 
bin 
config 
config.ru 
Gemfile 
Rakefile 
README.rdoc
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the flags -d postgresql -T and change the database to postgresql by hand in the Gemfile.  The instructions for doing so can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Comment: The adapter was already set to `adapter: postgresql` , as well as, my `Gemfile` having the `gem 'pg'` Unfortunately, I am those things are not the source of the problem : / I ran `rails new` without the `-d -T` but it produced the same result. I end up with a default program that only has these inside of it and it seems to me that there should be more than that in a default file which, coupled with the initial error, alerted me that somethign isn't right :                                         
app
bin
config
config.ru
Gemfile
Rakefile
README.rdoc

Comment: You probably want to delete the flags from .railsrc then

Comment: I deleted the `.railsrc` file but I still get the same error message when I try and create a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with railties. For some reason, the file is not in [the expected gem path](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/postgresql.yml).

You should try to reinstall railties. Try with:

```
gem uninstall railties
gem install railties
```

If that doesn't work, I think you must to reinstall rails.

PS: If the last option is your choice, you could give a try to [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). Maybe is not part of the problem, but it will help you to manage your ruby versions and gems in a better way.